# THF-H2O mixture at 80°C? isn't THF supposed to evaporate completely?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, vapor-pressure, evaporation

I was running a synthesis of TiO2 nanoparticles starting from a aqueous solution of TiCl4 *2THF 0.125M at 80°C. Through a different experiment it was detemined that the maximum reaction yield was 96% at 30 minutes after the start (mixing of TiCl4*2THF with H2O at 80°C).
THF is used in this complex just to prevent a strong exothermic mixing with water, but it doesn't take part in the reaction.
Having said that, I thought that THF, after dissociating from the complex, was in the solution with a concentration of 0.25M. Since the temperature was 80°C and the boiling point of pure THF is 66°C, I considered the THF evaporating completely in 30 minutes.
My problem is trying to demonstrate by a theoric approach that THF leave the system.

I tried to use the raoult law : P(THF)= P°(THF)*X(THF) but I get a small value of partial pressure of THF.

I'll give you some more info: P°(THF) at 80°C = 1.54 atm , X(THF)=0.0047, P°(H20) at 80°C = 0.46 atm X(H2O) = 0.993

I am not sure about the right way to demonstrate the THF evaporation (30 min at 80°C), could you please help me?

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: It depends on how fast you remove the vapours, what is evaporation kinetics and what is the threshold THF content to be considered negligible (as it is exponential process, less THF = slower evaporation).

Comment: @Poutnik I don't how to estimate the evaporation kinetics. The system is a open one, so the equilibrium between the vapour phase and liquid phase it's only temporary. Do you know any mathematical equation that can explain the evaporation rate of the solution, including the THF?

Comment: As there are several unknown variables,  you have to rely on empirical parameters. You may measure the evaporation rate via mass or volume decreasing rate. From that you can estimate the rate of THF evaporation via molar fraction in vapour.

Comment: The (lab scale) synthesis of NPs often uses round bottom flasks because 1) it is typical equipment already in the shelves, 2) ease to heat/cool by baths, 3) ease to connect to Schlenk lines, 4) ease to mount additional equipment such as [dropping funnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropping_funnel) (with pressure equalization), or an efficient reflux [condenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condenser_(laboratory)) (Dimroth model).  What's the remaining problem?  Get a syringe pump if the addition by the dropping funnel still is too fast (but: this is more expensive than the funnel).